# AWS AppSync Alternative in GCP

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, aws-appsync

I'm using AWS AppSync (GraphQL) for an API that is connected to Lambda and S3. Now, we are planning to migrate this to Google Cloud Platform. Could someone help me understand if there are any Services/options available in Google Cloud Platform that provides similar services like AWS AppSync?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run a serverless GraphQL on [Google Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/) or Firebase which is the closest thing to [AWS AppSync](https://aws.amazon.com/appsync/) available today on GCP.

Comment: "One drawback to take note of when using GCP Functions is that GraphQL subscriptions are not able to be supported due to the nature of the GCP Functions." is a 2018 note, which seems to still be true. Ref: https://codeburst.io/apollo-graphql-server-express-google-cloud-function-serverless-framework-dbb6b5cf4bb3

Comment: Seems like you can use Google PubSub to alleviate that: https://github.com/axelspringer/graphql-google-pubsub